# mySQL auto increment doesn't adjust to changes in database

Tags: mysql

So I have auto increment on my primary key. I was under the impression that if I have:

1.
2.
3.
4.

And remove two, I won't end up with this:

1.
3.
4.

But rather:

1.
2.
3.

Is this not the function of auto increment? If so, what is this I'm trying to achieve, and how can I do it?

Comment: You were under the wrong impression.  The database does not re-value auto-incremented ids.  If it did so, then all the foreign key relationships would be wrong.

Comment: "what is this I'm trying to achieve, and how can I do it" --- why do you want PK to be consecutive gapless numbers at first place? What's wrong with `1; 3; 4;` PK values?

Comment: How might I re-value the keys? Is there a query to do this? If not, I presume I wouldn't even use auto-increment at all?

Comment: I have a table displaying entries. A user can enter let's say 7, and then click a button. The 7th row on the table would then be removed. Hence why I need consecutive numbers.

Comment: @tyler5819: what if user enters 999999999? What would you show?

Comment: An error message. But this is for a prototype I'm creating, so as long as I can get it to work, it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove `2` from a set of `1,2,3,4` you end up with `1,3,4` - this keeps the identifying feature of each record, i.e. its primary key, intact, If you think about it, this is a good thing: Imagine a user clicking "delete 3" while you just deleted 2, so changing the meaning of "delete 3" while it is under way.

If you want to select a consecutive number together with some rows, use something like

```
SELECT
  -- fieldlist
  @num:=@num+1 AS rownum
FROM 
  -- table
  , (SELECT @num:=0) AS init
WHERE
 -- ...
```

Comment: The way it'll be used for, this wouldn't be an issue. Now would that query re number the primary key or?

Comment: It would NOT renumber the PK, which I heavily discourage you to do. You should display `rownum` but keep the real PKs (possibly invisible). When the user enters 7, you chose the 7th **real** PK and use it to delete the record.

Comment: Or if the user wants to delete the 5th entry, is there a query that will select the 5th entry currently in the database?

Comment: There is: `SELECT primarykeyfield FROM TABLE ORDER BY {same order as original table} LIMIT 5,1` for the 5th row.

Comment: @tyler5819: why do your users rely on order not on actual PK values? If you try to delete this question - stackoverflow will reqest `question.id = 23353617` deletion, not `question 424242th` deletion.

Comment: @tyler5819: another example: if 2 users simultaneously request to delete 7th entity - they will drop 2 rows, not one as they would expect. This wouldn't happen if you used PK values as-is.

Comment: There's only one user who will be doing deletions. But I will try @EugenRieck's query.

Comment: @tyler5819: even if it will be a single person - your solution is poor from relation theory point of view.